# Суммирование вводимых чисел и выход с цикла словом

Tags: java

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int sum = 0;
    while (true){
        String x = reader.readLine();
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(x);
        if (x.equals("сумма")) {
            System.out.println(sum);
            break;
        }
    }
}}
```

Задача такова: вводи числа с клавиатуры, плюсуй их, при написании слова "сумма" выводить сумму. Компилится, запускается, но после ввода слова, начинает ругаться. Какие-то непонятки с типом переменной как я понимаю. Подскажите как исправлять сеё безобразие.

PS 
ругательства:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "сумма"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
```

Comment: Код ошибки, пожалуйста.

Comment: Если в функцию [parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) передали строку, которую нельзя представить как число, то это вызывает ошибку `NumberFormatException`. Если вы пока не умеете обрабатывать ошибки, то перенесите суммирование ниже условия `if`.

Comment: Да, ещё совсем зеленый, благодарю)

Comment: О, человек, который знает и использует ``.equals()`` уже совсем не зеленый!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int sum = 0;
    while (true){
        String x = reader.readLine();
        if (x.equals("exit")) {
            System.out.println(sum);
            break;
        }
        int y = Integer.parseInt(x);
        sum = sum + y;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Программа пытается преобразовать эту строку в число, вызывая `Integer.parseInt(x)`. Если введенная строка не является корректным числом (в вашем случае это слово "сумма"), то `Integer.parseInt()` бросает исключение `NumberFormatException`.

Для исправления нужно сначала проверить, содержит ли введенная строка слово "сумма", и только если нет, преобразовывать строку в число и добавлять ее к сумме. Вот исправленный вариант вашего кода:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int sum = 0;
        
        while (true) {
            String x = reader.readLine();
            if (x.equals("сумма")) {
                System.out.println(sum);
                break;
            } else {
                sum += Integer.parseInt(x);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Таким образом, цикл прекращается при вводе слова "сумма".